# Как вытащить значение из ответа?

Tags: python, telethon

С помощью библиотеки telethon хочу взять id всех участников канала. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

api_id = 1027ххх
api_hash = '35b7ac0969621e90404f55f0ac5ххххх'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
participants = client.get_participants('t.me/joinchat/AAAAAE2DSCVFUoxDrXjK8Q')
d = participants[0]
print(d)
```

В ответ получаю:

```
User(id=730888010, is_self=True, contact=True... )
```

Как мне из этого ответа вытащить id?

Answer (score 1):

Класс [`User`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/user.html) имеет поле id, то есть:

```py
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
participants = client.get_participants('...')
d = participants[0]
print(d)
print(d.id) # <---
```